# Is it necessary/advisable to uninstall QGIS 1.8 first before installing 2.0?

Tags: qgis, mac, osx

Who has installed QGIS 2.0 on Mac OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)? Is it necessary/advisable to uninstall QGIS 1.8 first? Have you seen any problems importing QGIS 1.8 projects to 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the 2. version It will overwrite the 1.8 version (QGIS.app).

But,I use everyday versions 1.8, 2. and [master](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/) on Mac OSX 10.6.8 without problem (often at the same time).

So, the only thing you need to do is to rename the version 1.8 in QGIS1.8.app , otherwise, it will be deleted (QGIS.app)

Comment: Great - it works. There are a lot of problems with 2.01; I'm sticking with 1.8 excepting one map where I need to increase marker line thickness.